# Java Array / Program Issue

Tags: java, arrays

Ok, so I am working on a java program for my college class and I have now spent many hours trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

My program is below. What it needs to do is convert an integer into single digits and then add them all up. It has to display the original number, the individual digits and then the sum.

Part of the project is it has to accept negative digits and then display the positive numbers and the sum, however with my array it is displaying a -1 as the first number when a negative number is input and I CANNOT for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

Example: input of -3456 ends up displaying -1, 3, 4, 5, 6 and a sum of 17 which is obviously wrong.

Any help would be immensely appreciated, thanks!

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; //import package for using dialog boxes
import java.util.Arrays; //import package for arrays

public class Project4
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {   

//declares and initialize variables sum & counter
      int sum = 0;
      int counter = 1;



//asks for integer input and stores as a string in numInput
      String numInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter an integer: ", "User Input", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); 
      int input = Integer.parseInt(numInput);//parses the value of numInput as an integer and stores as input

      int numLength = String.valueOf(input).length();//sets numLength as the length of input
      int [] varArray = new int[numLength];//initilizes an array to match numLength

      if(input == (-input))//tests for negative input value
      {

         input = (input * (-1));//corrects the negative input value

            for (int i = 0; i < numLength; i++ ) //starts a for loop
            {

               String var = numInput.substring(i,counter);//stores the value of the number at the location between i and counter as var

               int numVal = Character.getNumericValue(var.charAt(0));//sets numVal to the numeric value of the character at 0

               varArray[i] = numVal;//saves the numVal to the array at position i

               sum = sum + numVal;//adds the sum of the numbers as the loop goes

               counter++;//increments the counter
            }
      }

      else //starts alternate loop if input was not a negative value
      {         
            for (int i = 0; i < numLength; i++ ) 
            {

               String var = numInput.substring(i,counter);

               int numVal = Character.getNumericValue(var.charAt(0));

               varArray[i] = numVal;

               sum = sum + numVal;

               counter++;

            }
      }

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Digits of Integer Entered " + input + " are: " + Arrays.toString(varArray).replace("[", "").replace("]", "") + "\nThe sum is: " + sum, "NUMBERS", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      System.exit(0); //exits program and is required when using GUI

   }
}
```

Comment: After  `input = -input;` (rather than multiplying with -1) you have a non-negative number. It is, therefore, not necessary to duplicate the code (if you adjust the numInput string).

Comment: If you don't have to store the digits in an array, an *arithmetic* computation of the sum of the digits is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(input == (-input))
```

doesn't test for negative inputs, it tests if the input is 0.

```
if(input < 0)
```

tests for negative input.

Answer (score 1):

Always avoid an if.

```
input = Math.abs( input );
```

This takes care of the sign and doesn't need an if.

While I'm at it, this is the preferred way to compute the digit sum (provided you don't need to store the digits in an array, from left to right):

```
int sum = 0;
while( input > 0 ){
    sum += input%10;
    input /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Condition

```
if(input == (-input))
```

By

```
if(Math.signum(input) == -1.0)
```

Or

```
if(input < 0)
```

Comment: Agree , But if u want to check it by built in method then u can use it

Comment: Aw, shucks. you could call Math.exp(input) and see whether it is >= 1. :-)  In any real-world organization you'd get a reprimand for coding in a circuitous way.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  int integerNumber = Integer.parseInt(input);//It may positive or negative
  if(integerNumber > 0) {
      //Do the stuff positive number
  } else if(integerNumber < 0){
       integerNumber = (integerNumber * -1);
      //Do the stuff for negative number

  } else {
     System.out.println("Enter Number is zero ::");   
  }
}catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
  System.out.println("Please Enter a Integer Number :::"+input);
}

//I think this code will help for you.
```